# Stack Overflow, Programmers, or Code Review?

Tags: support, questions, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

If I have a question related to python (although I assume this applies to any programming language), I know I should use the python tag, but how do I determine among the SE sites with a python tag - ie Stack Overflow, Programmers, and Code Review?

I thought reading the 'about' section of each would help, but it didn't. I thought reading questions already posted would help, but I'm still confused.

Is there a place to go to find out the 'scope' of a site and how to resolve overlaps? Particularly for my specific case of python.

Comment: The respective FAQ pages don't help either?

Comment: What's the nature of the question?

Comment: detailed guidance is given in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in